# Running Play Framework 2.0 on Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, playframework-2.0

I can't find any information about deploying Play Framework **2.0** on Tomcat, is it even possible? If so, where can I find any info regarding it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sadly, it is not supported in the Play 2.0 release. Looks like the feature got pushed to 2.1, here is the [the ticket](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/8-war-packaging).

#### Update

There is a plugin that aims are war support for Play 2: https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin/

Comment: Thanks! Also thankfully it turned out I was allowed to use Heroku instead of local tomcat :)

Answer (score 2):

The Asynchronous IO model is not supported by Servlet 3.0 containers. See post by one of the committers below:

"We are experimenting with this right now, however, it looks like what we need is JSR-340
JSR-340:
http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=340
timeline for JSR-340:
http://java.net/projects/servlet-spec/lists/users/archive/2012-03/m...
based on the timing it looks unlikely that this will be part of 2.1, so I am changing the milestone to "none"."

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin.

https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin

It's not flawless as of now (April 2012) but there is a lot of commits done every day.

Answer (score -2):

The call for play framework 1.2 is 
    play war myapp -o myapp.war

I'd try that in  play framework 2, although it's not in the documentation any more. Unfortunately I can't try if it still works because I don't have play on this machine.