# How to deploy Play framework 2.2.5 on tomcat 6?

Tags: java, tomcat, playframework-2.2

My application is developed on Windows 7 and Play framework 2.2.5. After dist command i had snapshot.zip file. How to configure my app on Tomcat 6 web server?  Zip file consists of bin, conf, lib, share folders and README file.

Comment: `play war myapp -o myapp.war`, then put your war into /tomcat/webapps folder and run it.

Comment: Before i read Play framework 2.2.X not support war generate. Cause i can't generate war file.

Comment: You are right, take a look at this SO thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737562/running-play-framework-2-0-on-tomcat

Comment: import com.github.play2war.plugin._  this line github package not found error in my plugin.sbt