# Scala and play 2 framework hosting what are the requirements

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am new to scala and play 2 framework and would like to know if they can be hosted on a webhost that has Tomcat, JSP, and Java Servlet hosting. I would obviously include the scala files.

Comment: did you read https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.0.2.1/deployment

Comment: @singhakash OP's obviously asking for Play 2.x what can be determined by title, content, and tags, please point the proper documentation.

Comment: sorry uploaded wrong docs check [Play 2.0 on tomcat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737562/running-play-framework-2-0-on-tomcat)

Answer (score 1):

Per the documentation, all you need on your server is JRE6 or later.  Play does not use Tomcat, JSP or Java Servlets.  Play will create a standalone distribution for you with the `play dist` command.  Copy that to a server with Java installed and you're ready to go.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ProductionDist